# How can I use SetWindowsHookEx with ffi in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, winapi, hook, ffi

I want to listen keyboard events use windows hook, we can do it with SetWindowsHookEx use MethodChannel, but I want to do this with dart code use ffi, I write some code but it doesn't work in flutter, I can't receive any message from windows after I called SetWindowsHookEx, here is some of my dart code:

```dart
final _kernel32 = DynamicLibrary.open('kernel32.dll');
final _user32 = DynamicLibrary.open('user32.dll');

late final HHOOK _hhk;

int hookproc(int code, int wParam, int lParam) {
  return _CallNextHookEx(_hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void setWindowsHook() {
    const idHook = WH_KEYBOARD_LL;
    final lpfn = Pointer.fromFunction<LRESULT Function(Int32, WPARAM, LPARAM)>(
      hookproc,
      0,
    );
    final hmod = _GetModuleHandleW(nullptr);
    const dwThreadId = 0;
    _hhk = _SetWindowsHookExW(idHook, lpfn, nullptr, dwThreadId);
}

late final _GetModuleHandleW = _kernel32
    .lookup<NativeFunction<HMODULE Function(LPCWSTR)>>('GetModuleHandleW')
    .asFunction<HMODULE Function(LPCWSTR)>();

late final _SetWindowsHookExW = _user32
    .lookup<NativeFunction<HHOOK Function(Int32, HOOKPROC, HINSTANCE, DWORD)>>(
        'SetWindowsHookExW')
    .asFunction<HHOOK Function(int, HOOKPROC, HINSTANCE, int)>();

late final _CallNextHookEx = _user32
    .lookup<NativeFunction<LRESULT Function(HHOOK, Int32, WPARAM, LPARAM)>>(
        'CallNextHookEx')
    .asFunction<int Function(HHOOK, int, int, int)>();

late final _UnhookWindowsHookEx = _user32
    .lookup<NativeFunction<BOOL Function(HHOOK)>>('UnhookWindowsHookEx')
    .asFunction<int Function(HHOOK)>();
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal here? It's not common for users to struggle with low-level keyboard hooks when all they want is to [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey).

Comment: @IInspectable Oh, I just use the keyboard event to test wheather I can receive the hook message, I want to use hooks to detect some events like device add and remove

Comment: If you want to monitor device removal and arrival, [register for device notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/registering-for-device-notification).

Comment: register device notification need also need a WinProcCallback to receive hook message, it's not easy without MethodChannel, so I want to use SetWindowsHookEx to intercept the messages with dart:ffi

Comment: [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationw) takes a service or window handle of your choosing. There is no requirement to hijack a window or its associated message processing.

Comment: The window is created by flutter, how can we receive the messages without go to the native side?

Comment: Create your own window then. Obviously, that requires calling into the OS through its API. Whether that can be done through Flutter or requires that you directly call into the OS I don't know. But since you have already settled on using a hook it's unlikely that a platform-agnostic implementation is a design goal.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks, I finally solve this by create a [message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) on the dart side

Comment: @iAMD can you share the full result you came with? ran into similar issue